# run spring boot application on azure container registry instance

Tags: azure, spring-boot, docker, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I'm trying to run a spring boot application on azure. This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

local project > Azure Devops Git Repos > Azure container registry

From my local, I push the changes to Azure Devops Repos. Repository has a pipeline that does maven package, create docker image and push the image to Azure Container registry. And I'm running the container image using Azure container instance. Container instance is deploying successfully, but when I try to access a rest api defined in spring boot application, nothing happens. Page keeps on loading.

I try to access the GET api like this:

my_public_ip:8080/hello

DockerFile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/command-center.jar command-center.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/command-center.jar"]
```

azure-pipeline.yaml

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'f4031dc5-3c27-4f41-be8c-2abdf064eaf2'
  imageRepository: 'commandcenter'
  containerRegistry: 'sapcemission.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '**/command-center/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  
  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Maven@3
      inputs:
        mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
        publishJUnitResults: true
        testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
        javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
        mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
        mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
        effectivePomSkip: false
        sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

Azure container instance settings:

[image: Azure container instance settings]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Container Instance doesnt support port mapping like docker. So in your case when you setup ACI, port property should be set to 8080 (not default 80).